# How to solve operator>> overloading error (no match for 'operator>>')

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I've looked through other topics about this and tried to see if I can find my error, but I wasn't able to find out how to solve my error.

My error:

```
no match for ‘operator>>’ (operand types are ‘std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}’ and ‘Polynomial()’)
cin >> p3;
```

main:

```
// includes, namespace, etc...

int main()
{
    Polynomial p3();

    // Prompts user and assigns degrees and coefficients
    cout << "Enter the degree followed by the coefficients: ";
    cin >> p3;

    // other coding
 }
```

Header file definition for operator >>:

```
class Polynomial 
{
      private:
          double *coefs;
          int degree;
      public:
          // constructors, setters/getters, functions
          friend std::istream &operator >>(std::istream &in, Polynomial &poly);
};
```

Implementation file:

```
Polynomial::Polynomial() // default constructor
{
    degree = 0;
    coefs = new double[1];
    coefs[0] = 0.0;
}

std::istream &operator >>(std::istream &in, Polynomial &poly) ////!!!!!!
{
    in >> poly.degree;

    delete[] poly.coefs; // deallocate memory
    poly.coefs = new double[poly.degree + 1]; // create new coefficient array

    for(int i = 0; i <= poly.degree; i++) // assigns values into array
    {
        in >> poly.coefs[i];
    }

    return in;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My attempt at value initialization is interpreted as a function declaration, and why doesn't A a(()); solve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/my-attempt-at-value-initialization-is-interpreted-as-a-function-declaration-and)

Comment: Aka the most vexing parse

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Polynomial p3();` is a function declaration, not a variable definition (as you expected). It declares a function named `p3`, which returns `Polynomial` and has no parameters. Also note the error message, it says operand type is `Polynomial()`, which is a function.

Change it to

```
Polynomial p3;
```

or

```
Polynomial p3{}; // since C++11
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe a simple error gave me so much problems. Been looking at this problem for over an hour before seeking help.
Really appreciate it! Will accept answer after the time is up!